# Optimisation sqlite application statup

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application download datas from webservice JSON at start up. Then i need to store those data in an sqlite database.

The operations are pretty heavy on the system, application start up and list loading is too sloww :(

Here is how i do things :

- Application startup
- Launcher Activity
- If connectivity is ok, download JSON (with Volley)
- Store in SQLite (with SQLHelper)
- Start Main activity
- Load from database to cache (List, ArrayList.. etc)
- I need to do sql request for sorting, filtering... etc

Download is made in threads since it's network oparations, sql operations are on mainthread since i need it for the list

What can i improve for better performance ?

Comment: If the data that you're downloading is not changing too often, you can precache the data for the first run and have a separate service update the data every few hours/days or so.

Comment: The data are to change according to location of the user in his city/country.

Comment: even if your data cannot be precached. I guess it's always a good idea to separate out updating the db from your main app and put it in a background service. then at the first launch user should still wait for the service to finish updating or user can use as much data that is so far downloaded by the service into the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on very first run, nothing to do (after app installed) ask user to wait with an alert dialog, after that, make those operations in a service, independent of your application, so that by the time the user opens the app, the data is already there, no need to download again

also you could download the data in small chunks, and display to the user what you have already downloaded, and tell him there may be more

Comment: I don't really have a choice, the data are provided by only ONE json stream. So i can't download bit by bit. and i need to get those data from network for the firstrun, it's necessary (it can't be prepatch in the application)

Comment: how long does it take to download the data?

Comment: close to 15sec download, 15sec to insert in the database. it needs to be updated each time the user start the application and has connectivity(the connectivity part is ok).

Comment: what is wrong with updating this info in a service once a day?

why must it be "at the start of the application" ?

Comment: Because the application have been coded by another person and I lack time to change everything ^^so i was hoping for some simple hack that can help me optimize this quickly

Comment: sometimes there is no simple hack but rewriting the code entirely

good coding doesnt always sum up to good algorithms, and clean code - but to good strategy

if you have to download something heavy every time the user opens up the app, the user will not want to use the app... i wouldn't.. this is what ANRs are for

Comment: Well you are right at least thanks for trying ^^ I will have to think it up a little more :/